# How processes communicate about IPC parameters?

Tags: c, unix, posix, ipc, shared-memory

I was reading about Shared Memory in POSIX and came up with this function to establish a shared memory

```
segment id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

`IPC_PRIVATE` is used to create a new segment for a process. Now my question is how does the process on the other end know the segment_id to communicate? If at all the initiating process is sending it the information, then how can it do so without having initialized the mechanism to do so first?

When I read more about it, I found out that a process has to attach itself to a shared memory region. But to do so, we require id of the shared memory. How is it obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Talking in the context of server-client model, it is like this.

The server can create a new IPC structure by specifying a key of `IPC_PRIVATE` and store the returned identiﬁer somewhere(such as a ﬁle) for the client to obtain.

The key `IPC_PRIVATE` guarantees that the server creates a new IPC structure.

The disadvantage of this technique is that ﬁle system operations are required for the server to write the integer identiﬁer to a ﬁle, and then for the clients to retrieve this identiﬁer later.

There are various ways for a client and a server to rendezvous at the same IPC
structure.

Comment: Any idea about how it happens within the same system?

Comment: And also could you please tell any one way to rendezvous at the same IPC structure?

Comment: The above description is valid also within the same system. Server-client model is a generic term.

Comment: Any mechanism to agree on the parameters before the communication starts? That's what's I'm looking for....

Comment: @darknight Hardcode a name in the applications. Or have a system administrator call the programs that need to communicate to start them with the same command line argument - the IPC key. Note that IPC_PRIVATE is pretty much only useful to share memory from a parent process to a child process created with fork() - for unrelated processes, you'd create a key with the ftok() call instead of using IPC_PRIVATE.